# How to connect bevy game to externel TCP server using tokios async TcpStream?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, bevy

I want to send Events between the game client and server and I already got it working, but I do not know how to do it with bevy.

I am dependent to use tokios async `TcpStream`, because I have to be able to split the stream into a `OwnedWriteHalf` and `OwnedReadhalf` using `stream.into_split()`.

My first idea was to just spawn a thread that handles the connection and then send the received events to a queue using `mpsc::channel`

Then I include this queue into a bevy resource using `app.insert_resource(Queue)` and pull events from it in the game loop.

the Queue:

```rs
use tokio::sync::mpsc;

pub enum Instruction {
    Push(GameEvent),
    Pull(mpsc::Sender<Option<GameEvent>>),
}

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Queue {
    sender: mpsc::Sender<Instruction>,
}
impl Queue {
    pub fn init() -> Self {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel(1024);
        init(rx);
        Self{sender: tx}
    }
    pub async fn send(&self, event: GameEvent) {
        self.sender.send(Instruction::Push(event)).await.unwrap();
    }
    pub async fn pull(&self) -> Option<GameEvent> {
        println!("new pull");
        let (tx, mut rx) = mpsc::channel(1);
        self.sender.send(Instruction::Pull(tx)).await.unwrap();
        rx.recv().await.unwrap()
    }
}

fn init(mut rx: mpsc::Receiver<Instruction>) {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let mut queue: Vec<GameEvent> = Vec::new();

        loop {
            match rx.recv().await.unwrap() {
                Instruction::Push(ev) => {
                    queue.push(ev);
                }
                Instruction::Pull(sender) => {
                    sender.send(queue.pop()).await.unwrap();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But because all this has to be async I have block the `pull()` function in the sync game loop.
I do this using the `futures-lite` crate:

```rs
fn event_pull(
    communication: Res<Communication>
) {
    let ev = future::block_on(communication.event_queue.pull());
    println!("got event: {:?}", ev);
}
```

And this works fine, BUT after around 5 seconds the whole program just halts and does not receive any more events.

It seems like that `future::block_on()` does block indefinitely.

Having the main function, in which `bevy::prelude::App` gets built and run, to be the async `tokio::main` function might also be a problem here.

It would probably be best to wrap the async `TcpStream` initialisation and `tokio::sync::mpsc::Sender` and thus also `Queue.pull` into synchronous functions, but I do not know how to do this.

Can anyone help?

### How to reproduce

The repo can be found [here](https://codeberg.org/BrunoWallner/Apoxel)

Just compile both `server` and `client` and then run both in the same order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it to work by just replacing every `tokio::sync::mpsc` with `crossbeam::channel`, which might be a problem, as it does block

and manually initializing the tokio runtime.

so the init code looks like this:

```rs
pub struct Communicator {
    pub event_bridge: bridge::Bridge,
    pub event_queue: event_queue::Queue,
    _runtime: Runtime,
}
impl Communicator {
    pub fn init(ip: &str) -> Self {
        let rt = tokio::runtime::Builder::new_multi_thread()
            .enable_io()
            .build()
            .unwrap();
    
        let (bridge, queue, game_rx) = rt.block_on(async move {
            let socket = TcpStream::connect(ip).await.unwrap();
            let (read, write) = socket.into_split();
            let reader = TcpReader::new(read);
            let writer = TcpWriter::new(write);
        
            let (bridge, tcp_rx, game_rx) = bridge::Bridge::init(); 
            reader::init(bridge.clone(), reader);
            writer::init(tcp_rx, writer);
        
            let event_queue = event_queue::Queue::init();
        
            return (bridge, event_queue, game_rx);
        });
    
        // game of game_rx events to queue for game loop
        let eq_clone = queue.clone();
        rt.spawn(async move {
            loop {
                let event = game_rx.recv().unwrap(); 
                eq_clone.send(event);
            }
        });
    
        Self {
            event_bridge: bridge,
            event_queue: queue,
            _runtime: rt,
        }
    }
}
```

And `main.rs` looks like this:

```rs
fn main() {
    let communicator = communication::Communicator::init("0.0.0.0:8000");

    communicator.event_bridge.push_tcp(TcpEvent::Register{name: String::from("luca")});

    App::new()
        .insert_resource(communicator)
        .add_system(event_pull)
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .run();
}

fn event_pull(
    communication: Res<communication::Communicator>
) {
    let ev = communication.event_queue.pull();
    if let Some(ev) = ev {
        println!("ev");
    }
}
```

Perhaps there might be a better solution.